# Kafka Producer Call Method Initialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using following code block to send Kafka Messages,
Do I need to initialize `CallBack` at each message sending? Instead Can I use only single instance callback?

```
@Override
    public void produce(String txnLogStr) {
      ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, txnLogStr);
      producer.send(record, new ProducerCallback());
   }
```

pom.xml

```
 <!-- KAFKA-QUEUE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which kafka version you are using?

Comment: I am using without call back method, check method `send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record)` in `KafkaProducer.java` class, it intern uses `send(record, null);` my kafka version is 0.8, use `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.1</version>
        </dependency>` and give it a try

Comment: I have updated the question with kafka version

Comment: @dkb Callback is required for tracking.